# Laravel : One to many relational data update

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have the following code :

```
foreach ($request->dog_vaccine_required as $key => $vaccine) {
    $serviceVaccination = \App\UserServiceVaccination::updateOrCreate([
        'user_service_id' => $id,
        'vaccine_id' => $vaccine
    ],[
        'specie' => 'Dog',
        'user_service_id' => $id,
        'vaccine_id' => $vaccine,
        'duration_6' => $request->dog_duration_6[$key],
        'duration_12' => $request->dog_duration_12[$key],
        'duration_36' => $request->dog_duration_36[$key]
    ]);
}
```

Now the data coming along from the form is :

[image: Form data]

It gives me exception :

> Undefined offset: 2

The request `dog_duration_6`, `dog_duration_12`, `dog_duration_36` arrays can be different in terms of element size,

How can i pass null to avoid exception `Undefined offset: 2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a check like to avoid offset **exception**.:

`isset($request->dog_duration_6[$key]) ? $request->dog_duration_6[$key] : null`

For all of them.

Comment: In PHP 7 you can use a shorter form with a ternary operator:
`$request->dog_duration_6[$key] ?? null;`
This performs the check with `isset()` and returns the value if it is set. Otherwise it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'duration_6' => $request->dog_duration_6[$key] ?? null,
```

Comment: To explain this answer: `$request->dog_duration_6[$key] ?? null;` 
This performs a check with `isset()` and returns the value if it is set. Otherwise it returns `null`.